# Can any body plx help me in this ...

Tags: java, data-structures

Im facing problem when i use to run this program.this is continuously repeating the case 1 .`

```
import java.util.Scanner;    //importing 

public class DynamicStackByArray {   // name of class

    private static String[] a;
    private static int size;

    public DynamicStackByArray(){} // end of the null constructor

    public DynamicStackByArray(int capacity){

        a=new String[capacity];
    }// end of the  parameterized constructor


    private static String peek(){
        if(size==0)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Stack is Empty");
        else 
            return a[size-1];
    }// end of the displaying method

    private static String pop(){
        if(size==0)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Stack is Empty...");
        else{
            String o=a[--size];
            a[size]=null;
            return o;
        }
        }// end of the pop method
    private static void push(String o){
        if(size==a.length)resize();
        else
            a[size++]=o;
    }// end of the push method

    private static void resize(){
        String aa[]=a;
        a=new String[1+aa.length];
        System.arraycopy(aa, 0, a, 0, size);
        aa=null;
    }// end of the resize method

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the size of dynamic stack :");
        int cap=in.nextInt();

        DynamicStackByArray d=new DynamicStackByArray(cap);

        System.out.println("Enter your choice \n1) for push\n2) for pop\n3) for peek");
        System.out.println("Enter -999 to exit");

        int choice=in.nextInt();

        while(choice!=-999){
            switch(choice){

            case 1:{
                System.out.println("Enter your desire data");
                System.out.println("Note that -999 will let u escape out of it... :)");

                String input;
                input=in.nextLine();
                String as="-999";

                if(!input.equalsIgnoreCase(as)){
                    d.push(input);

                }// end of checker
                System.out.println("Enter your choice \n1) for push\n2) for pop\n3) for peek");
                System.out.println("Enter -999 to exit");

                 choice=in.nextInt();
                break;
            }// end of case 1
            case 2:{
                System.out.println("Value "+d.peek()+" has been poped ");
                d.pop();
                System.out.println("Enter your choice \n1) for push\n2) for pop\n3) for peek");
                System.out.println("Enter -999 to exit");

                 choice=in.nextInt();
                break;
            }// end of the case 2
            case 3:{
                System.out.println("Value "+d.peek()+" has been peeked");
                System.out.println("Enter your choice \n1) for push\n2) for pop\n3) for peek");
                System.out.println("Enter -999 to exit");

                 choice=in.nextInt();
                break;
            }// end of the case 3
            default:{
                System.out.println("Sorry this is a wrong choice...");
                System.out.println("Enter your choice \n1) for push\n2) for pop\n3) for peek");
                System.out.println("Enter -999 to exit");

                 choice=in.nextInt();
                 break;
            }// end of default

            }// end of the switch statement
        }// end of the repetation of the program

        System.out.println("GOOD BYE... !!!");
    }// end of the main method
}// end of the class
```

`

Comment: In `push` remove `else` otherwise the stack loses one element.

Comment: k. and please tell me that when i use to run it. then when i enter 1 for push then it runs continuously and don't come out of case 1.

Comment: as @user3256871 is saying: it is not executing just case1 all the time

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to ask scanner for input inside your loop. You can fix it :

```
int choice = 0;
while ((choice = in.nextInt()) != -999) {

    //... your loop
}
```

One more important thing :

 in `case 1:` when you read `input=in.nextLine();` it will consume `\n` symbol that was used to terminate "1" input and your `String input` will be always empty string. (just put a breakpoint and verify it yourself) 

Therefore, you have to add extra `nextLine()` statement inside case 1:

```
in.nextLine(); // read `\n` symbol;
String input = in.nextLine();
```

Comment: As best I can tell, this is wrong. Every `switch` case in the loop contains a `choice=in.nextInt();` statement at the end. This is certainly a better way of doing it (assuming you remove the existing `choice=in.nextInt();` statements), but it doesn't look like it will fix the problem.

Comment: @Dukeling true, didnt notice it

Answer (score 0):

It is not executing just case1 all the time. The program is running correct. You just made mistake by take peek method in both cases, u should use pop method in case2 as u desired for.